# Which is faster between php switch case or database query in this context

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have an online php/mysql based Bible search app. Currently it only have 5 book versions.

I am now being asked to add 130+ Bible versions. I am thinking if this will have impact on the performance.

The options I am considering are as follows.

**OPTION 1**:
Hard code the different bookname and use php switch case to determine the book to display. This is my current setup and this is working well for 5 languages currently added on my app. I did it this way because the database I receive only have book number column and has no bookname.

In case language selected is African (same process for all other languages), below code will check book number and apply name appropriately (66 Bible books)

```
case "101": $book ="101"; $bookword = ("GENESIS" . ' ' . strval($chapter_id) . ':' . strval($verse_id)); break;
case "102": $book ="102"; $bookword = ("EXODUS" . ' ' . strval($chapter_id) . ':' . strval($verse_id)); break;
case "103": $book ="103"; $bookword = ("LIVITIKUS" . ' ' . strval($chapter_id) . ':' . strval($verse_id)); break;
...
case "166": $book ="166"; $bookword = ("OPENBARING" . ' ' . strval($chapter_id) . ':' . strval($verse_id)); break;
```

This will be run every time user change language selection via pull down menu

**OPTION 2**: 
Add a column `bookname` in each tables (each table is one Bible version) which will mean additional  31 thousand entries for each books. This way, bookname will already be included in the query result. In **option 1**, only book number is available after query. I have to use the php switch case to add bookname.

Will there be significant difference between these 2 in terms of performance.

Comment: done, I'd be careful pigeon holing 1.3bn people across 1200+ languages and 51 countries as just "African", this site has a lot of international users. Are you sure you didn't mean the Southern African/Namibian language of Afrikaans?

Comment: sorry I didn't get that. The African was just an example of a selected language. That is the first language I am about to add out of 130. Hence I use it as an example.

Comment: 5 vs. 130, no, the database won't blink an eye.  If you have a nice foreign-key table listing all of the versions-ids and you've appropriately subdivided the content by version-id you could have thousands of versions and the system *still* won't blink.  Build your system in the simplest and most straightforward manner and "don't borrow trouble."

Comment: @MikeRobinson thanks for that insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there won't be a significant difference in performance. Databases are made for this sort of thing, and maintaining the code for this manually would be hell (and error-prone).